# Better way to set default value in django model field

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

I am implementing a field in django model which calls the following function for default value

```
def get_default_value():
    a = MyModel.objects.aggregate(max_id=Max('id'))
    return get_unique_value_based_on_num(a['max_id'] or 0)

class MyModel:
    default_value_field = CharField(default=get_default_value)
```

Although I may be wrong on this, I fear this implementation may result in race condition.

Is there a better way to do this ? May be use F object or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid race conditions, it is best letting the database handle the integrity of your table, which is one of the things databases are made for.

To do so, catch any `IntegrityError` raised by saving your model instance and try again with a different value when it fails.

```
from django.db import IntegrityError, models, transaction


def get_default_value():
    a = MyModel.objects.aggregate(max_id=Max('id'))
    return get_unique_value_based_on_num(a['max_id'] or 0)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # Have unicity enforced at database level with unique=True.
    default_value_field = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def save(self):
        if not self.default_value_field:
            max_tries = 100  # Choose a sensible value!
            for i in range(max_tries):
                try:
                    self.default_value_field = get_default_value()

                    # Atomic block to rollback transaction in case of IntegrityError.
                    with transaction.atomic():
                        super(MyModel, self).save()
                        break
                except IntegrityError:
                    # default_value_field is not unique, try again with a new value.
                    continue
            else:
                # Max tries reached, raise.
                raise IntegrityError('Could not save model because etc...')
        else:
            super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I am currently checking out  `select_for_update`  to see if that will work out. I guess this is also a valid alternative approach so accepting it. Wouldn't there be `break` after `save` inside the loop ?

Comment: @sagarchalise I did not know about `select_for_update` but it seems to be exactly what you are looking for, if you manage to use it to solve your issue, you should post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like django has `select_for_update` for queryset API. It may be the solution to my problem.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update